# How to trigger my apex code when a role is created or updated?

Tags: salesforce, role

Now we have a business logic which needs to relate a custom object with Role directly. Salesforce don't allow us to create lookup relationship with Role.
We intend to save Role Name and Id on contact, but it's a hard-code solution, the contact role name can't change when the role name changed. Did anybody met this situation? How to solve this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Role is not an object in Salesforce that can be used in the same way standard objects (account, contact, campaign etc) or custom objects can.  Role **is** accessible as a field on the user object which is potentially confusing.  It doesn't appear as a standard object when you look at "Setup | App Setup | Customize" nor is it one of the choices available in "Related To" when you create a lookup relationship field on an object.

It should be possible to access role information via the metadata API:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/

Role does appear there (as userrole).  I haven't done this myself, but this post says that it is possible to access the metadatapi from within Apex:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/has-anyone-ever-successfully-invoked-the-metadata-api-from-within-apex

Comment: Role can be accessed by apex. My question is about how to create lookup relationship between Role and Custom Objects. As temporary solution, We use a custom role object to replace standard Role.

Comment: My first sentence was unclear.  Role is accessible as a field on the user object, but it doesn't appear as a standard object when you look at Setup | App Setup | Customize.  It's not one of the choices available in "Related To" when you create a lookup relationship field on an object.  I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

As temporary solution, We use a custom role object to replace standard Role.